# Hiding desktop top panel through a shortkey. Is this possible? ( I am not talking about "auto-hide".)

Tags: gnome, 18.10

**This is Ubuntu 18.10.** 
Is there some sort of "command" that I can assign to hide top panel which shows time, date etc?

> *Note: I have tried this "Dash to panel" extension which I really loved it but the assigned shortkey didn't respond:*

### [image: Screenshot]

When I press Super and "O", nothing really happens. It Should reveal/hide the panel as it says? Or, am I assigning the shortkey the wrong way.

> Fullscreening every app is not an option I want to use.

Comment: are you looking this for dash-to-panel or default ubuntu-dock or dash-to-dock??

Comment: `<Super>+o` or `<Super>o` will make it..

Comment: Wow, that really solved the entire problem. Thanks a lot @PRATAP

Answer (score 0):

`<Super>+o or <Super>o`  is how we assign shortkey in "Dash to panel" extension for autohiding the short key.

> (Note: u can select any other alphabet in case of "o")

And I think, there is no command to hide the top panel bar.